# Log of BIOS events for HP PC?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, bios, uefi

I have an HP EliteDesk PC and I would like to know if there is a log of BIOS events somewhere. I have not been able to find one when browsing in the Startup menu of the BIOS. Below is a picture of the Startup menu when I access to the BIOS.

[image of the Startup menu when I access the BIOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUGOK.png)